# Is there a way to signal a coroutine when producer is exhausted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a coroutine pipeline for an event-driven data pipeline. Everything is working great so far. I wanted to try processing some of the input in batches but need a way to ensure that the final batch is processed once the upstream producer is empty. In the contrived example below, this would be a way to `print(res)` in `print_data_cp` once `produce_data_from` was done. A more direct analog would be to print and reset `res` each time its length == 3 and guarantee that the remaining values in res are printed once the producer is done. I know there are several ways to solve this but  is there a idiomatic approach to this problem (e.g. sentinel value, return remainder, while/finally, wrap in class)?

For now, I have the coprocess function as part of a class and let `res` be an instance variable so I can access it after the the coprocess function is complete. This works but something like a while/finally would be more general.

```
def produce_data_from(data, consumer):
    next(consumer)
    for x in data:
        consumer.send(x)

def print_data_cp():
    res = []
    while True:
        x = (yield)
        res.append(x)
        print(x)

cons = print_data_cp()
produce_data_from(range(10), cons)
```

Answer (score 0):

This modification uses try/finally and changes the producer to close the consumer coprocess. This triggers the finally block. Here, the coprocessor relies on the producer sending the `close()` signal, so modifying the consumer function to batch process requires modifying the upstream producer function as well. Not ideal, but it works and feels pythonic enough. I would be delighted to see other approaches.

```
def produce_data_from(data, consumer):
    next(consumer)
    for x in data:
        consumer.send(x)
    consumer.close()

def print_data_cp():
    res = []
    try:
        while True:
            x = (yield)
            res.append(x)
            if len(res) >= 3:
                print(res)
                res = []
    finally:
        print(res)

cons = print_data_cp()
produce_data_from(range(10), cons)
```